# How to prevent for sum of decimals in Excel to be rounded?

Tags: excel, rounding

I have two values in Excel that when added they are rounded automatically

```
Value a 8.572469279842190
Value b 5.208000000000000
Total  13.780469279842200
```

[image]

Same thing happens using VBA

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    
    a = 8.57246927984219
    b = 5.208
    c = a + b
    
    MsgBox c

End Sub
```

[image]

Any idea on how to prevent this?

Comment: You can't. Excel only stores 15 digits of precision. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/

Comment: Very few *practical* calculations need that many digits of precision, in any case. But if you have some that do, Excel is not the right tool to use.